# Are all sequences in $\Bbb Q$ that have no convergent subsequences unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that in the metric space **R** all sequences with only nonconvergent subsequences must be unbounded. Would the same apply to sequences in the metric space **Q**?

A sequence that seems to disprove this is the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

Edit: Shouldn’t the above sequence have a convergent subsequence in **Q** as it could be contained in a compact subset of the rationals (namely the closed interval from 2 to 4)?

Comment: You have answered your own question ...

Comment: The sequences consisting of the digits of all irrational numbers provide counter-examples.

Answer (score 1):

> A sequence that seems to disprove this is the decimal expansion of $\pi$.

Indeed, you've answered your own question.

> Edit: Shouldn’t the above sequence have a convergent subsequence in **Q** as it could be contained in a compact subset of the rationals (namely the closed interval from 2 to 4)?

The closed interval $[2,4]$ **is not** a subset of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$. It contains irrational numbers, in particular $\pi\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ to which the sequence converges.

On the other hand the intersection $[2,4]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ but it is not compact.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Shouldn’t the intersection you’ve mentioned be compact by Heine-Borel since it is both closed and bounded in **R**?

Comment: Never mind, because **Q** is dense in **R**, the interval isn’t closed, so Heine-Borel cannot be used.

Comment: @FullerAlexander4 your last comment seems to be full of misunderstandings: (1) being dense or not is irrelevant, $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, (2) the interval isn't a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, being closed is meaningless, (3) even though $[2,4]\cap\mathbb{Q}$ is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$, being closed isn't that important, compact is and (4) Heine-Borel applies to subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, not to subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$. That's the real reason. It may seem that it should, cause $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, but closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ need not be closed in $\mathbb{R}$.